# FST_ERR_REP_ALREADY_SENT when trying to sendFile on Nestjs notfoundExecption

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify

I want to serve spa app with nestjs and fastify, it works but when I refresh a 404 is triggered. So I wrote an exception to catch the 404 and send the file but I keep getting FST_ERR_REP_ALREADY_SENT error.

My code below

```
import { Catch, ExceptionFilter, ArgumentsHost, HttpException, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FastifyReply } from 'fastify';

@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class NotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(_exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse() as FastifyReply;
    response.sendFile('index.html');
  }
}
```

I want 404 to serve the index.html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past and an update from Nest 8 to 9.x fixed the bug. @Cavdy you may want to update to the latest Nest, atleast anything >=9 and you should be good to go.

Comment: this was the case for me... I had to upgrade my packages

Answer (score 0):

It's probably catching something on `notFoundHandler` before it reaches your exception filters. I recommend setting it on `notFoundHandler` instead of using exception filters [reference](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#setnotfoundhandler)